# Getting PC to connect to Fixie Proxy

Tags: heroku, proxy

I have a Fixie Proxy server that works fine when my Heroku Node.js apps use it.

My question is, is there any way for my computer to use this proxy? I'm trying to access another server that only this fixie proxy can connect to but am unable to do so. I've tried adding in the Fixie url, port, etc in my proxy server settings in my OS (I've tried both Mac and Windows).

From what I've read, it looks like Fixie is just designed to work with code and Heroku apps. However, there must be some way to just have a machine connect to it?

Thanks